# Java - Fullscreen limits the FPS to 60

Tags: java, fullscreen, frame-rate

I am currently programming a small game as a side project and for the first time I tried to implement multiple possible resolutions (via graphics scale) and a fullscreen mode.

I figured it would be better to implement this right at the beginning of the development and so far it works fine.

But I made a strange observation. When in Windowed Mode the game is running as intended with a tickrate (amounts of updates per second) of 60 and a unlimited FPS (rendering per second) rate.

But when I switch into fullscreen it goes down to a fixed tickrate of 60 and **fixed FPS of 60**.

Which is very strange in my eyes. The command I use to switch to fullscreen.

```
if (device.isFullScreenSupported()) {
    device.setFullScreenWindow(frame);
}
```

Project Files:

Window class: (Initiates the Window and Switches between Fullscreen and Windowed)

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GraphicsDevice;
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Window extends Canvas {

    private JFrame frame;
    private int height;
    private int width;
    private double scaleX;
    private double scaleY;
    private String title;
    private Game game;
    private boolean fullscreen = false;
    private GraphicsDevice device;
    private GraphicsEnvironment ge;

    public Window(int width, int height, double scaleX, double scaleY, String title, Game game) {
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        this.scaleX = scaleX;
        this.scaleY = scaleY;
        this.title = title;
        this.game = game;
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        frame = new JFrame(title);
        ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
        device = ge.getDefaultScreenDevice();
        frame.getContentPane().setMinimumSize(new Dimension((int) (width * scaleX), (int) (height * scaleY)));
        frame.getContentPane().setMaximumSize(new Dimension((int) (width * scaleX), (int) (height * scaleY)));
        frame.getContentPane().setPreferredSize(new Dimension((int) (width * scaleX), (int) (height * scaleY)));
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.add(this, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setUndecorated(false);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void updateSize(int width, int height, double scaleX, double scaleY) {
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        this.scaleX = scaleX;
        this.scaleY = scaleY;
        frame.getContentPane().setMinimumSize(new Dimension((int) (width * scaleX), (int) (height * scaleY)));
        frame.getContentPane().setMaximumSize(new Dimension((int) (width * scaleX), (int) (height * scaleY)));
        frame.getContentPane().setPreferredSize(new Dimension((int) (width * scaleX), (int) (height * scaleY)));
        frame.pack();
    }

    public void setFullscreen() {
        if (!fullscreen) {
            game.setRender(false);
            frame.dispose();
            frame.setUndecorated(true);
            frame.setVisible(true);
            game.setRender(true);
            if (device.isFullScreenSupported()) {
                device.setFullScreenWindow(frame);
            }
            this.requestFocus();
            fullscreen = true;
        }
    }

    public void setWindowed() {
        if (fullscreen) {
            game.setRender(false);
            frame.dispose();
            frame.setUndecorated(false);
            frame.setVisible(true);
            game.setRender(true);
            device.setFullScreenWindow(null);
            this.requestFocus();
            fullscreen = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Game Class: (Game loop and main method)

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;

public class Game implements Runnable {

    // Version number
    private static final String Version = "0.1";
    // The game title
    public static final String TITLE = "Tapper";
    // The default width and height the game is build upon
    private static final int WIDTH = 800;
    private static final int HEIGHT = 600;
    // The scaling factor depending on the chosen resolution
    private double scaleX = 1.0d;
    private double scaleY = 1.0d;

    // Game Window
    private Window win;

    // FPS and tick variables to display in debug hud
    private int fps = 0;
    private int ticks = 0;

    // Pixel width of a string in a certain font
    private int stringLen;

    // Boolean tick, running and rendering variables
    private boolean running = false;
    private boolean tick = true;
    private boolean render = true;
    // Main game Thread
    private Thread gameThread;

    // Handles the Keyboard Input
    private KeyInputHandler ki;

    // Jugst for testing
    private double x;

    public Game() {
        win = new Window(WIDTH, HEIGHT, scaleX, scaleY, TITLE, this);
    }

    private void init() {
        // Initiate Handlers and objects
        ki = new KeyInputHandler(this);
        win.addKeyListener(ki);
    }

    public synchronized void start() {
        if (running) {
            return;
        }
        running = true;
        gameThread = new Thread(this);
        gameThread.start();
    }

    public synchronized void stop() {
        if (!running) {
            return;
        }
        running = false;
        try {
            gameThread.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void tick() {
        // Lets objects and handlers tick
        x = x + 0.09;
    }

    private void drawDebugHud(Graphics2D g2d, String fontName) {
        Font font = new Font(fontName, Font.BOLD, 12);
        g2d.setFont(font);
        g2d.drawString("G - Switch to Fullscreen", 5, HEIGHT - g2d.getFontMetrics().getHeight() * 6);
        g2d.drawString("H - Switch to Windowed", 5, HEIGHT - g2d.getFontMetrics().getHeight() * 5);
        g2d.drawString("Ticks:" + ticks, 5, HEIGHT - g2d.getFontMetrics().getHeight());
        g2d.drawString("FPS:" + fps, 5, HEIGHT);
    }

    private void drawVersionNumber(Graphics2D g2d, String fontName) {
        g2d.setFont(new Font(fontName, Font.BOLD, 12));
        stringLen = (int) g2d.getFontMetrics().getStringBounds("v" + Version, g2d).getWidth();
        g2d.drawString("v" + Version, WIDTH - stringLen, HEIGHT);
    }

    private void render() {
        BufferStrategy bs = win.getBufferStrategy();
        if (bs == null) {
            win.createBufferStrategy(3);
            return;
        }

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) bs.getDrawGraphics();
        /* DRAW EVERYTHING BELOW HERE */
        g2d.scale(scaleX, scaleY);

        // BACKGROUND
        g2d.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g2d.fillRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);

        // Everything else
        g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g2d.fillRect((int) x, (int) x, 40, 40);

        // Debug hud
        drawDebugHud(g2d, "Arial");
        drawVersionNumber(g2d, "Arial");

        /* DRAW EVERYTHING ABOVE HERE */

        g2d.dispose();
        bs.show();
    }

    public void run() {
        win.requestFocus();
        init();
        long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
        double amountOfTicks = 60.0;
        double ns = 1000000000 / amountOfTicks;
        double delta = 0;
        int updates = 0;
        int frames = 0;
        long timer = System.currentTimeMillis();
        while (running) {
            long now = System.nanoTime();
            delta += (now - lastTime) / ns;
            lastTime = now;
            while (delta >= 1) {
                if (tick == true) {
                    tick();
                    updates++;
                }
                delta--;
            }
            if (render) {
                render();
                frames++;
            }

            if (System.currentTimeMillis() - timer > 1000) {
                fps = frames;
                ticks = updates;
                timer += 1000;
                frames = 0;
                updates = 0;
            }
        }
        stop();
    }

    public Thread getGameThread() {
        return gameThread;
    }

    public void setTick(boolean tick) {
        this.tick = tick;
    }

    public boolean isTick() {
        return tick;
    }

    public double getScaleX() {
        return scaleX;
    }

    public void setScaleX(double d) {
        this.scaleX = d;
    }

    public double getScaleY() {
        return scaleY;
    }

    public void setScaleY(double d) {
        this.scaleY = d;
    }

    public static int getDefaultWidth() {
        return WIDTH;
    }

    public static int getDefaultHeight() {
        return HEIGHT;
    }

    public Window getWin() {
        return win;
    }

    public boolean isRender() {
        return render;
    }

    public void setRender(boolean render) {
        this.render = render;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Game().start();
    }
}
```

KeyInputHandler: (Just for testing purposes, used to switch between Fullscreen and Windowed)

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

// Handles the Keyboard Input

public class KeyInputHandler implements KeyListener{

    private Game game;
    private Dimension screenSize;

    public KeyInputHandler(Game game) {
        this.game = game;
    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        int key = e.getKeyCode();   

        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_G) {
            screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
            // calculating and setting the scaling factor
            game.setScaleX(screenSize.getWidth() / Game.getDefaultWidth());
            game.setScaleY(screenSize.getHeight() / Game.getDefaultHeight());
            // Switch to Windowed Mode
            game.getWin().setFullscreen();
            // Refresh window size
            game.getWin().updateSize(Game.getDefaultWidth(), Game.getDefaultHeight(), game.getScaleX(), game.getScaleY());
        }

        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_H) {
            // Calculating and setting and setting the scaling factor
            game.setScaleX(800d / Game.getDefaultWidth());
            game.setScaleY(600d / Game.getDefaultHeight());
            // Switch to Windowed Mode
            game.getWin().setWindowed();
            // Refresh window size
            game.getWin().updateSize(Game.getDefaultWidth(), Game.getDefaultHeight(), game.getScaleX(), game.getScaleY());
        }
    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {}

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {}
}
```

Does it has something to do with the fullscreen mode or is it something different in my code? Would love to see some replies that might help me out. :)

Comment: Wouldn't that have something to do with `double amountOfTicks = 60.0;`...?

Comment: This just determines the amount of ticks per second. The amount of renderring per second (how often the render method is called) is not limited. That is exactly what is strange in my eyes. It shouldn't be limited to 60 FPS.

Comment: But you have a `delta` loop which is based on `ns`, which is based on `amountOfTicks`, which is controlling when `render` (and `frames++`) gets called...(not that your delta loop is based on actual time value)

Comment: But the delta loop does not limit the FPS only the ticks. On this screenshot you can see that the FPS are not limited when in Windowed mode: http://i.imgur.com/azTT9kf.png

Comment: Why wouldn't the `delta` loop effect the FPS?  It can't render until the delta loop completes?

Comment: But the loop only runs through once. You can basicly replace the `while` in `while (delta >= 1) {` with an if. It will produce the same results. The delta loop only get's accessed every 100th or so time the `while (running) {` loop runs through, while the render method get's called every single runthrough.

Comment: You may be locked into the hardware refresh rate at full screen - Look this is just a personally thing, I'm not a fan of this type of game loop.  Without anything else, I had the CPU up to 70% just idling through your game loop, that's a lot of wasted CPU IMHO

Comment: That is actually a very good point. I didn't have the screen refresh rate in mind. I guess that is the solution. 

The game loop is also not finished. You are right, at the moment it produces way to high CPU load (40% for me). I will try to limit the rendering to little bit more than the screen refresh rate. This should keep it down a bit hopefully. If you have a suggestion maybe, I would love to hear it :)